# Korn shell getopts syntax error

Tags: shell, ksh, getopts

I am trying to write a Korn shell script that uses `getopts` to take command line options. The example given in the book I am using gives the description of using `getopts` with this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
a="not selected"
b="not selected"
b_arg="not selected"
c="not selected"
c_arg="not selected"
d="not selected"

while getopts "ab#c:d" optchar ; do
   case ${optchar} in
      a)  a="selected"
          ;;                # the ;; marks the end of this case

      b)  b="selected"
          b_arg=${OPTARG}
          ;;

      \?) echo "error message goes here"
          exit 1
          ;;
   esac
done
```

I am trying to write a Korn shell script that takes in `-c`, `-l`, `-p`, `-r`, and `-f` but when I change the loop to

```
c="not selected"
l="not selected"
p_arg="not selected"
p="not selected"
r_arg="not selected"
r="not selected"
f="not selected"

while getopts "clp#r:f" optchar ; do
   case ${optchar} in
     c)  c="selected"
         ;;                # the ;; marks the end of this case
```

I get an error that states "Syntax error on line 13: 'in" but if I just changed the variables in a string I don't understand how that causes a syntax error. Thank you for any help or explanation that points me in the right direction!

Comment: You've only given us 12 lines of script.  Where is line 13 that's giving the error?

Comment: You seem to have an extraneous `.` in your question that messes up the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
while getopts "ab#c:d" optchar ; do
```

What's that <kbd>#</kbd> character doing in there? Should be a <kbd>:</kbd>

```
while getopts "ab:c:d" optchar ; do
```

Comment: Hey Glenn thank you for taking the time to answer,I can post the whole code if that would help, I am getting the error "ksh fileOpts.ksh
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
' unexpected: line 10: syntax error at line 12: `in
"

Comment: Did you apply my suggestion?

Comment: The docs for `getopts` mention that "The option # can only be specified as the first option.", but it's unclear to me why that is true or what (if any) special meaning such an option has.

Comment: `getopts` is a ksh builtin, so read the ksh man page for getopts. My ksh man page says "optstring contains the letters that getopts recognizes.  If a letter is followed by a :, that option is expected to have an argument. " -- I read nothing about `#` in the optstring